# git unamend after rebase from remote

Tags: git

So I had this situation:
I didn't have the latest code in my local repo and i had raised code review and after approval , the merge failed.. so i had to do `gill pull origin mainline --rebase`. by mistake i did `git commit --amend`. Now its amended the previous commit to mine.. basically my changes got merged into previous one. rebase is also completed.

Now what i want to do is:

1. have my changed pushed to remote with latest changes as a separate commit instead of merged/amended one.

I tried to create a new branch in my local from mainline and then in mainline i tried doing `git reset --hard` . This also has amended commit.. how do i solve this?

Comment: try `git reset --soft HEAD@{1}`

Comment: Check `git reflog` for the commit ID of the original commit.